# Call an async method from within a class method in Swift

Tags: swift, async-await, class-method, xctestcase

I have a data library that needs to get loaded before all my tests. This works, but the data gets loaded before each test:

```
override func setUp() async throws {
   try await super.setUp()

   let task = Task {
      try await dataLibrary.load()
   }
    
   try await task.value
}
```

So I would like to move it to `override class func setUp()` which is called only once before all the tests:

```
override class func setUp() {
   super.setUp()

   let task = Task {
      try await dataLibrary.load()
   }
    
   try await task.value
}
```

First I get this error:

> 'async' property access in a function that does not support concurrency

So I fixed that by adding `async` to the method:

```
override class func setUp() async throws { ... }
```

But now:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

Is it possible what I am trying to do?

Comment: Are you just missing the `throws`? `override class func setUp() async throws { ... }`

Comment: I get the same error - I edited the example.

Comment: Show `dataLibrary.load()`. Why is it async?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible what I am trying to do?

I would ask rather: Is there any *need* to do what you are trying to do?

But first things first. Your original implementation was wrong:

```
override func setUp() async throws {
   try await super.setUp()

   let task = Task {
      try await dataLibrary.load()
   }
    
   try await task.value
}
```

It is pointless and silly to make a Task inside an `async` method, as you are *already* in a Task. Just say

```
override func setUp() async throws {
   try await super.setUp()
   try await dataLibrary.load()
}
```

Now, on to your actual question. First, I would question your assumption that there is some advantage to moving this call off to the class version of the tests. But let's go with that assumption for purposes of discussion.

Then, as you have rightly concluded, you face the fact that the class version of `setUp` doesn't come with an `async` variant. And this is reasonable, because this method is only going to run once, before all tests, so there is no harm in its being time-consuming.

So either `dataLibrary.load()` should not be `async` to begin with (since you are just going to wait until it has finished anyway) or else you need at least to provide a non-`async` version of it.

In particular, if this `dataLibrary.load()` is purely a testing utility, it should not be `async`, as there is no need for it to be. And on the other hand, if this is an method of your app, then you should not be calling it in `setUp`, because you shouldn't have any app dependencies in your `setUp` and `tearDown`; you need to provide a test-only implementation that does "the same thing" (whatever that may mean).

Comment: Understanding your thoughts here about `dataLibrary.load()` not having to be async. The function loads a file from the bundle and uses an `XMLParser` to parse the file and it has to complete before the tests start. I need to think more about that.

Comment: "The function loads a file from the bundle and uses an XMLParser to parse the file and it has to complete before the tests start." But it doesn't need to be async to do that. Why are we supposing that it does?

Comment: You are correct - that was my misunderstanding. I removed `async` from the parser code and all is well.